# closing ionic2 datetime popup, while pressing back button?

Tags: ionic2

I am using ionic2 ion-datetime, when I am going back in my application, still, date picker popup is showing, although there is no ion-data time tag in back page. help me to remove this pop on pressing back button

.html file

```
<ion-datetime id="dateofbirth" class="date" displayFormat="DD MMMM YYYY" [max]="maxDate" [min]="minDate">
```

.ts file(here i have written some logic for custom date time)

```
let date: any = new Date(),
        maxYear = date.getFullYear() - 18, minYear = date.getFullYear() -65,
        month = date.getMonth() + 1, minDay:any = date.getDate(),
        this.minDate = minYear + "-" + month + "-" + minDay;
        this.maxDate = maxYear + "-" + month + "-" + maxDay;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code in your .ts file where you have your component with ion date picker

```
ionViewWillLeave(){
        let backDrop: any = document.getElementsByTagName('ion-picker-cmp');
        if(backDrop.length > 0){
            for(let i = 0; i< backDrop.length; i++){
                backDrop[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Great! Welcome @Ani

Comment: Any solution for `ionic-4`?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your **app.component.ts** file in following way,

```
  import { Platform, IonicApp } from 'ionic-angular';

  constructor(public platform: Platform, private ionicApp: IonicApp){}

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      //back button handle
      this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
        let activePortal = this.ionicApp._loadingPortal.getActive() ||
          this.ionicApp._modalPortal.getActive() ||
          this.ionicApp._toastPortal.getActive() ||
          this.ionicApp._overlayPortal.getActive();

        if (activePortal) {
          activePortal.dismiss();
        }
      });
    });
  }
```